How to apply jsonnet's local-var rule?
Please help me understand the local-var rule from jsonnet's specification:

I'd like to understand it in general, but also, specifically, how does it apply to the following program found in the jsonnet reference manual?
local a = local x = 'a'; x;
local foo = local x = 'b';  a;
foo


Disclaimer: this reply comes from my jsonnet practical experience, I can barely read --if at all-- the language spec.
This is how I understand it: a local scope is opened by local (think if as { in other languages like C), and closed by ; (similar to })
Below example builds on yours, but adding indentation +comments to highlight the nested locality "level":
foo.jsonnet
local a =
  // level0 scope
  local x =
    // level1 scope
    local y =
      // level2 scope
      local z = '.';
      '1' + z;
    'a' + y;  // `z` here would be outside of scope
  x;  // `y` here would be outside of scope

local foo =
  // level0 scope
  local x =
    // level1 scope
    local y =
      // level2 scope
      local z = ',';
      '2' + z;
    'b' + y;  // `z` here would be outside of scope
  a + x;  // `y` here would be outside of scope
foo

output
$ jsonnet foo.jsonnet
"a1.b2,"

